# how to display a specific value in Shiny as a percentage

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to format the display output of numbers (in dataframe below) to percentage in Shiny R output.
Essentially, I am displaying numbers in three rows: "X1", "X2", "X3". At the moment, my output is like:
X1: 0.6692
X2: 0.8466
X3: 0.5890

What I'd like to have is
X1: 66.92%
X2: 84.66%
X3: 58.90%

I tried using scales::percent instead of the "round" but I am getting errors. I was wondering what is the easiest way to do this? Thank you all in advance.

```
output$pred_info <- renderReactable({
a<-PRED_res_CI()
req(a)
a<-t(a)
rownames(a)<-c("X1","X2","X3")
a<-a[c(1,3,2),]

reactable(round(a %>% data.frame(),4),style = list(fontFamily = "sans-serif", fontSize = "1.3rem"),
          
          rowStyle = JS("function(rowInfo) {
  return { background: '#eee', borderLeft: '2px solid #ffa62d' }
```